# Unable to extract Body from Twilio Request

Tags: java, twilio

When I send a specific message to my Twilio number, I want to take an action depending on what that message is. The problem is, `request.body()` is returning the entire request, not just the body.

I've followed the Twilio guide for creating a webhook here:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-receive-and-reply-java
and have modified it to look at what the request body is, compare that with what I'm looking for, then respond as required.

The problem is as described, when I look at `req.body()`, I get more than just the body.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int portNumber = 80;

    if(args.length > 0){
        portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }

    port(portNumber);

    get("/", (req, res) -> "Hello Web");

    post("/sms", (req, res) -> {
        res.type("application/xml");
        System.out.println(req.body());

        String messageToSpend = req.body();

        if (req.body().equals("hello")){
            System.out.println("You said hello");
        }

        Body body = new Body
                .Builder(messageToSend)
                .build();
        Message sms = new Message
                .Builder()
                .body(body)
                .build();
        MessagingResponse twiml = new MessagingResponse
                .Builder()
                .message(sms)
                .build();
        return twiml.toXml();
    });
}
```

So, Spark starts up fine, then I set the URL accordingly in Twilio, then send a message.  The message is received, but the `System.out.println(req.body());` is returning this:

> ToCountry=GB&ToState=&SmsMessageSid=SMc52bea78ca1df688d3d20cxxxxxxxxxx&NumMedia=0&ToCity=&FromZip=&SmsSid=SMc52bea78ca1df688d3d20cxxxxxxxxxx&FromState=&SmsStatus=received&FromCity=&Body=Hello&FromCountry=GB&To=%2B44xxxxxxxxxx&ToZip=&NumSegments=1&MessageSid=SMc52bea78ca1df688d3d20cxxxxxxxxxx&AccountSid=AC4394b4cfb2bdcefb90c592xxxxxxxxxx&From=%2B44xxxxxxxxxx&ApiVersion=2010-04-01

Whereas I would have expected (in this instance) `Hello`.

I'm confused because I see `Hello` in there, with the appropriate `Body` tag, but it's not parsing just that.

Comment: It looks like you are confusing the Request's Body with a Request paramenter named Body. They are different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like spark parses post form data as queryParams (it is weird because the name implies GET). So

1. Do not call req.body() to avoid earlier consumption.
2. Call req.queryParams("Body") instead.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

       int portNumber = 80;

       if(args.length > 0){
           portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
       }

       port(portNumber);

       get("/", (req, res) -> "Hello Web");

       post("/sms", (req, res) -> {
           res.type("application/xml");
           // Remove this: System.out.println(req.body());

           String messageToSpend = req.queryParams("Body");

           if ("hello".equals(messageToSpend)){
               System.out.println("You said hello");
           }

           Body body = new Body
                   .Builder(messageToSend)
                   .build();
           Message sms = new Message
                   .Builder()
                   .body(body)
                   .build();
           MessagingResponse twiml = new MessagingResponse
                   .Builder()
                   .message(sms)
                   .build();
           return twiml.toXml();
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you, that did it.

As a bonus, in the meantime I learnt how to use StringUtils to get the Body myself, so the temporary workaround I did had a benefit!

Comment: Hi @PaulJohnson, now you can accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @mnesarco, apologies for the noob question, but how do I accept the answer?

Comment: Hi @PaulJohnson, just click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.